# Getting the string value of selected item in select menu

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have the following codes for a select menu:

```
<label for="select-choice-0" class="select">Shipping method:</label>
<select name="select-choice-0" id="select-choice-1">
   <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
   <option value="rush" >Rush: 3 days</option>
   <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
   <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
</select>
```

Doing $('select-choice-1').val() will give me the value of the selected option, for eg, if the second option has been selected, then, the value returned would be "rush".

However I want to get the string "Rush: 3 days" instead. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the following works:

```
document.getElementById('select-choice-1').options[document.getElementById('select-choice-1').options.selectedIndex].text;
```